# Returning all data from django backend

Tags: python, django

I have this problem, that my backend does not return all data. It returns the database table rows, that the token of the logged user matches the user's id of the model.

Here is the Blog model

```py
 class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts', null=True)
```

And here is the class that returns the data

```py
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    serializer_class = BlogSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.posts.all()
```

How can I return every row from the db regardless of the user who posted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you instruct it to return the `.posts.all()` of the logged in user. If you want to return all rows, you can just return:

```
from app.models import Blog

class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    serializer_class = BlogSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Blog.objects.all()
```

You can also remove the `IsAuthenticated` permission if users do not need to authenticate to retrieve the list of `Blog`s.